# Can I apply webkit-gradient to a border or just background?

Tags: html, css

So I would like to make the border faded. I have the exact webkit-gradient settings that I want.

But not sure how to implement it on the border element.

Is it possible? How do I do that?

Only CSS3 please.

Btw, I tried the following CSS and it didn't work:

```
border-color: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.74, rgb(214,11,11)), color-stop(0.39, rgb(175,13,13)), color-stop(0.07, rgb(157,22,22)));
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can apply `-webkit-gradient` to a border:

```
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00abeb), to(#fff), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #66cc00)) 21 30 30 21 repeat repeat;
```

[(from this example on webkit.org)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/LayoutTests//fast/gradients/border-image-gradient.html?format=raw)

[See the blog post on Webkit.org about `-webkit-gradient`](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/)

Comment: @Josh Border Image gradients are style VERY VERY Broken, but if you want to risk it, you COULD hack something together (It won't work very well if you change zoom levels or on this or that browser) http://jsfiddle.net/MWaTw/ [tested in google chrome]

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/borders.htm
Nice little article

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, this is how I applied a right border gradient on a div where the top and bottom ends fade out. Seems like it took forever to figure out... This is only for Safari as doing the same thing in Firefox is a lot easier...

http://jsfiddle.net/fkFec/1102/

```
<div class="g">
   <div>bla</div>
</div> 

.g {
    border-right-width:1px;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0, transparent), color-stop(0.5, grey), color-stop(0.5, grey), color-stop(1, transparent)) 0 100%;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```