# Border left gradient

Tags: css

That is my css:

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 31px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 31px solid transparent;
border-left: 31px solid #0caa3f;
```

Is it possible to make border-left have a gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fg7Ex/3/

```css
#grad {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 32px;
  clip: rect(auto 30px 60px auto);
}

#grad:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left bottom, color-stop(.75, #52882d), color-stop(0, #eee));
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```

*Shamelessly picked up from here*: https://gist.github.com/distilledhype/582201

Comment: +1  Seems that you are the only one that has **read** the question

Answer (score 1):

You can check the same kind of question in stackoverflow for solution [right border gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050158/right-border-gradient)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/fkFec/1547/)

There is no cross-browser css solution as it only supports chrome and firefox. So I recommend using div as parent and assigning it css:

```
.gradient {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.33, rgb(173, 14, 173)), color-stop(0.67, rgb(255, 0, 255)));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(173, 14, 173) 33%, rgb(255, 0, 255) 67%);
    padding: 2px;
}
.gradient > div {
    background: #fff;
}
```

here is html:

```
<div class="gradient">
    <div>text in div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a box-shadow on a pseudo element of the div. Something like

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Fq8GM/1/)**

```
div:before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 3px;
    box-shadow: -3px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    left: -30px;
    top: -31px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--color:#777;

margin:0 1%;
padding:0 5%;
background:linear-gradient(to right, transparent, var(--color) 5%, transparent 5%, transparent 95%, var(--color) 95%, transparent);
```